# Difference between two for loops

Tags: bash, loops

What's the difference, if any, between these two `for` loops in bash?

```
for i in {1..3}; do
```

and

```
for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
```

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second form, you can manipulate the loop index within the body of the loop.  If the index is not modified, they are functionally equivalent:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo $((i++)); done
1
2
3
$ for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do echo $((i++)); done
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The other difference is that `{1..3}` is expanded *before* the loop starts, so you actually have

```
for i in 1 2 3; do ...
```

Not a big deal for small ranges, but if you have a huge range (perhaps tens of millions), it can eat up a significant chunk of memory.

On the other hand, in my anecdotal testing, the C-style arithmetic loop is much slower.

```
$ memused() { pmap "$1" | tail -1; }

$ memused $$; time for ((i=1; i<=10000000; i++)); do :; done; memused $$
 total            23208K

real    0m27.556s
user    0m27.604s
sys 0m0.028s
 total            23208K

$ memused $$; time for i in {1..10000000}; do :; done; memused $$
 total            23208K

real    0m17.221s
user    0m16.788s
sys 0m0.480s
 total          1898112K
```